# CRUD not working in Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error message":
NO route matches [POST]"/subjects/create"

I have directed the "create action" to "list" but still
The list is working fine put I can not get it to post new data into my database.
Coud any one point me into the right direction.

```
Controller:

class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    list
    render('list')
  end

  def list
    @subjects = Subject.order(:all)
  end

  def show
     @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @subject = Subject.new
  end

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
   if @subject.save
    redirect_to(:action = 'list') 

   else
       # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
   end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rewrite it to read (you didn't put the hash rocket in correctly)

`redirect_to(:action => 'list')`

Comment: well spotted on the hash rocket but I am still getting this error

Comment: Eicke This is what I have in my Routes file. Please explain what you mean
thanks

    SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do
  
    root :to => "demo#index"
  
  
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
    end

Comment: GET /:controller(/:action(/id:(.:format))) :controller#:acttion

Comment: Please just try it with `resources subjects` in your `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

The `No Route Matches` error is because the url for the `create` action is not `/subjects/create` its just `POST /subjects`

Comment: You're pretty much matching the right things I guess. Not sure why that wouldn't work.